# Why 'eval "MYVALUE=mystring" export MYVALUE' only works from bash and not zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, export, eval, zsh

I'm trying to figure out why the following command only works from `bash` and not from `zsh`:

Bash:

```
bash-3.2$ eval "MYVALUE=mystring" export MYVALUE
bash-3.2$ echo $MYVALUE
mystring
```

Zsh:

```
➜  ~ eval "MYVALUE=mystring" export MYVALUE
➜  ~ echo $MYVALUE

➜
```

I expected `zsh` to print `mystring` but instead it doesn't print anything.

It looks like `export` can't read the value which has just been parsed, but effectively `eval` is working, because if I run this other command using `zsh`:

```
➜  ~ eval "MYVALUE=mystring" env | grep MYVALUE
MYVALUE=mystring
```

it works as expected!

Can anyone please help me to figure out why the eval / export thing doesn't work with `zsh` but works with `bash` and how eventually make it work with `zsh` too? Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you using `eval` at all? What's wrong with `export MYVALUE=mystring` or `MYVALUE=mystring; export MYVALUE`?

Comment: @glennjackman sorry but you are missing some context here. I need to `eval` a more complex script and export a few variables which are defined inside this script. With bash everything works, with zsh it doesn't. I narrowed down the problem to eval / export thing to make it easier to reproduce and get help.

Comment: @glennjackman you actually suggested a valid solution :) if I do `eval "MYVALUE=mystring"; export MYVALUE` it works on both bash and zsh. Let's see if there are other methods but this definitely works for me!

Comment: I'm not a zsh user, so I can't offer you anything more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between bash and zsh in this respect is not related to eval, but in a subtle difference related to *export*.

You execute `eval` with 3 parameter:

```
"MYVALUE=mystring" 
export 
MYVALUE
```

Now the zsh man page (at least of my zsh version) is a bit misleading in its description of what eval is doing when it is invoked with more than argument, but a simple experiment shows what is going on:

```
eval 'A=BBBBBB' 'printenv A'
```

outputs *BBBBBB*. In fact, eval seems to string its arguments together into a single string, but separates the pieces by a space. Hence in your case,

```
eval "MYVALUE=mystring" export MYVALU
```

is equivalent to

```
eval "MYVALUE=mystring export MYVALU"
```

which in turn is simply

```
MYVALUE=mystring export MYVALU
```

and here is a difference between bash and zsh:

While in both shells, a statement of the form

```
A=B C
```

executes C where in a modified environment where A is set to B, the bash *export* is a command and "sees" the modified environment. This means that in

```
A=B export A
```

the bash export command "sees" the setting of A and exports the variable. In zsh, the export is simply a keyword and the modified invironment is ignored.

Therefore, you need either two separate statements in zsh, for instance

```
eval "MYVALUE=mystring;" export MYVALUE
```

or rewrite it as

```
eval export "MYVALUE=mystring"
```

Of course this leaves still the question, why you are using eval in the first place.

Comment: oh sorry! I only saw you posted an answer after I posted mine below. I can accept your since you took all this effort to reply.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of try and error and thanks to the hint from @glenn-jackman I can say that a possible solution that works with both `bash` and `zsh` is:

```
eval "MYVALUE=mystring"; export MYVALUE
```

Basically we need to add `;` before the `export`